# IBAction From UIView's File Owner Not Working in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController that loads a subview which is a `UIView` in a xib file. I connected the File's Owner to ViewController by adding the ViewController class as the File's Owner to the `UIView` xib in interface builder. Then I cmd + dragged from the `UIView` to the ViewController and created an `IBAction`.

I double checked everything by checking the Received Actions of File's Owner in IB of the `UIView`. It shows that the button is connected to the function of the in my ViewController. When clicking the button nothing happens. I am unsure why this is. Any help is appreciated.

I created another project doing the same steps and that works perfectly fine.

Comment: If it worked fine doing it from scratch, delete all your connections and re-attach them.

Comment: I tried that as well. in fact I deleted the entire file then recreated it and tried to connect all functions again but my efforts were to no avail. For now I created a delegate in my UIView which handles all my clicks and forwards it to my ViewController however I would rather connect straight to my VC rather than go the extra step.

Answer (score 0):

Add `deinit` to your view controller and set a breakpoint, or `print` something out within `deinit`, and I'm pretty sure you'll find your controller has been deallocated, at which point your wired-up `@IBActions` aren't hittable.

**Add to your ViewController...**

`deinit {
  debugPrint("deinit hit")
}`

Without your code...

I'm assuming you're showing the `ViewControllers.view` but not retaining a reference to the `ViewController` via a variable.

If you're not pushing the `ViewController` onto a navigation or tab bar controller's `viewController` stack, or managing pushes and shows via segues, you'd need to persist a reference to the actual `ViewController` instance somewhere in the form of a variable.